# MySQL LIKE statement for comma separated numbers

Tags: mysql

This is not a duplicate since I've tried all the solutions which I managed to find here. I don't even know how to include my question in the title.

I have numeric values in the column:

```
+-----------+
| tags      |
+-----------+
| 1,14      |
| 2,3       |
| 2,4       |
| 1,14      |
| 2,3,4     |
| 1         |
| 9         |
| 1,2,15,16 |
| 1,3,17    |
| 1,18      |
| 2,3,4     |
| 20,21     |
+-----------+
```

And I want to select a post where tag = 1, for instance.

If I act like this

```
"SELECT * FROM articles WHERE tags LIKE '%1%'";
```

MySQL will return all the post tagged: 14, 15, 16, 21... any other number, which contain "1";

I've been trying a lot of statements that gave me nothing such as:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE CONCAT(',', tags, ',') LIKE ? ORDER BY date_pub DESC LIMIT 4", "%,$tag_id,%")->fetchAll();
```

etc;

Unfortunately, every time I face the same result. MySQL returns all the numbers, which contain "1".

In other words, 1, 13, 127494849040450, 3900000000000001, everywhere MySQL sees "1", it will return the article.

But my goal is to grab the unique **number** from the comma separated VARCHAR string and return the article, which has such **numeric** tag.

I would appreciate if anyone may assist me with this issue.

Comment: But still, I would like to find a solution.

Comment: whilst @David is Correct, an intermediate step would be to use a `delimiter` value to always appear before and after the number, no matter what, so `1` becomes `,1,` and `2,3,4` becomes `,2,3,4,` and then you can simply use that delimiter in your LIKE clause

Comment: I don't understand the question - do you want all the values in tags if any tag is = 1 ? Then what?

Answer (score 3):

For this problem there is the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', tags)
```

If you want to use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE CONCAT(',', tags, ',') LIKE '%,1,%'
```

or better use `CONCAT()` for the parameter `'1'` too:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE CONCAT(',', tags, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', '1', ',%')
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you would correct the problem (rather than address only a symptom and prolong the root cause) would be to normalize the data so you're not using comma-separated values.  This would simplify the data, improve query performance, and prevent problems exactly like the one you're experiencing.

---

Having said that, you may be able to maintain your workaround with something like this:

```
WHERE `tags` = '1' OR `tags` LIKE '1,%' OR `tags` LIKE '%,1,%' OR `tags` LIKE '%,1'
```

This assumes that you can't guarantee that the tags will always be in sorted order.  They are, after all, just a string and not a sortable list of numeric values.  If you *can* safely assume they'd always be in order, this should do the trick too:

```
WHERE `tags` = '1' OR `tags` LIKE `1,%`
```

Answer (score 0):

WHERE tags = '1' OR   tags like '1 ,%'

- Assuming the tags are in numeric order and 1 is first when present. Otherwise further clauses would be required.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression like aka [RLIKE](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-rlike-function.php) can be used here

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE tags RLIKE '(^|,)nn(,|$)'; -- where nn the need number
```

The regular expression match start of string or coma (^|,), then number what we need followed by coma or end of string (,|$)